# Android, Dronekit

Tags: android, remote-control, drone.io, dronekit

I am develop an application for Rover to management by joystick. I need to create remote control to set direction of moving rover (left, right, forward, back). I'm trying to realize it by following code:

```
ControlApi.getApi(mDrone).enableManualControl(true, new ControlApi.ManualControlStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onManualControlToggled(boolean b) {                
            }
        });
ControlApi.getApi(mDrone).manualControl(0, -0.5f, 0, new AbstractCommandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {                
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(int i) {              
            }
            @Override
            public void onTimeout() {
            }
        });
```

But I'm getting an error 3 in onError block. Also before that I can't enable manual control it always return false. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or maybe guide me to the right way?

I would realy apriciate if someone can help me. Regards!

**UPDATED**

Still no result
Now I'm trying to use

```
MavLinkCommands.sendManualControl(drone, x, y, z, r, button, new ICommandListener(){...});
```

But can't run this method because drone is null.
I generate it like this:

```
MavLinkDroneManager mavLinkDroneManager = 
new MavLinkDroneManager(mContext, mConnectionParameter, mHandler);
MavLinkDrone drone = mavLinkDroneManager.getDrone();
```

and method getDrone always return null.

**SOLVED**

If someone will encounter a similar problem, then the solution is quite simple. In total, you need to read the python documentation in more detail :)

All you need to do is override the channels using MAVLink command msg_rc_channels_override(); and the code with the solution will look like this:

```
VehicleApi.getApi(mDrone).setVehicleMode(VehicleMode.ROVER_MANUAL); //be sure the vehicle is in manual mode
VehicleApi.getApi(mDrone).arm(true); // and arm need to be true
```

by default chanel 1 is left-right, chanel 3 is forward-back.
If it does not work, check on the drones in which channels they are connected.
To move vehicle left set chanel 1 to 2000, right - 1000;
To move forward set chanel 3 - 2000, bacck - 1000;

I tested it on ArduRover but I think it should work with ArduPilot and ArduCopter.

```
    msg_rc_channels_override rc_override = new msg_rc_channels_override();
    rc_override.chan1_raw = 1000 //right; 2000 //left
    rc_override.chan3_raw = 1000 //back; 2000 //forward
    rc_override.target_system = 0;
    rc_override.target_component = 0;

    ExperimentalApi.getApi(mDrone).sendMavlinkMessage(new MavlinkMessageWrapper(rc_override));
```

For more instruction check this [link](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/issues/643)

Comment: Would you please share your logcat output?

Comment: @MinaSamy Thanks, for reply! There is not much in the logcat. At first ControlApi.ManualControlStateListener() returned false and after AbstractCommandListener() in onError blocks returned code error 3. That's all I get:( I could not even find the numbers of these errors. It seems that 3 is somehow related to gps navigation, but I'm not sure

Comment: I also tried to check the JavaDocs for those APIs but didn't find them. My guess is that your application needs some runtime permissions that might not have been granted.

Comment: @MinaSamy I do not think so, since I can control the drone by giving him points on the map over which he automatically rides. The problem is that in the documentation I can not find the possibility of manual control. But I'm realy appreciate for help